# protecting server tools with web interface (phpMyAdmin,APC monitor ...)

Tags: apache-2.2, security, ssh, web-server, ssh-tunnel

We have web server (debian lenny, standard LAMP). We have few tools useful for server monitoring/administration with web interface (phpMyAdmin,APC opcache monitor,serverstats,phpinfo...) and we would like limit access to them only for server admins. So I created apache virtual which has allowed access from localhost only. Server admins then make SSH tunnel to server. Virtual host:

```
<Directory /var/www/localhost/www/>
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
   allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost/www
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

My **question** is - is this reasonably safe? We do not use iptables/firewall. I know I can use SSL + http authentication also/instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is reasonably secure.  I think in this case you don't need a firewall for this.  But you should still be sure you're properly securing SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems safe to me, but you should use your firewall to be really sure. It's his dedicated job to accept or refuse connections depending on their original address.

I usually close every port except SSH and then install NXserver. You can even generate a specific client certificate to make sure only allowed clients who are in possession of this certificate and of a valid account on the server can login (you can also just use the SSH authentication). Of course you can do this directly with SSH but I find it easier with NX. This also speeds up the X display since NX is globally an optimized X client library.

[NX and debian](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/freenx.htm)

Comment: Thanks for advice. But I do not use X server, so NXserver is overkill for me.